# New Hangman Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am working on a Hangman game, but I am having trouble replacing the dashes with the guessed letter. The new string just adds on new dashes instead of replacing the dashes with the guessed letter.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
import random
import math
import os

game = 0
points = 4

original = ["++12345","+*2222","*+33333","**444"]
plusortimes = ["+","*"]
numbers = ["1","2","3"]




#FUNCTIONS

def firstPart():
    print "Welcome to the Numeric-Hangman game!"

def example():
        result = ""
        ori = random.choice(original)
        for i in range(2,len(ori)):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                        result = result + ori[i] + ori[0]
                else:
                        result = result + ori[i] + ori[1]
        return ori



# def actualGame(length):







#TOP LEVEL





firstPart()

play = raw_input("Do you want to play ? Y - yes, N - no: ")

while (play == "Y" and (points >= 2)):
    game = game + 1
    points = points
    print "Playing game #: ",game
    print "Your points so far are: ",points
    limit = input("Maximum wrong guesses you want to have allowed? ")
    length = input("Maximum length you want for the formulas (including symbols) (must be >= 5)? ")

    result = ""                                           #TRACE
    ori = random.choice(original)
    for i in range(2,len(ori)):
          if i % 2 == 0:
              result = result + ori[i] + ori[0]
          else:
               result = result + ori[i] + ori[1]   
    test = eval(result[:-1])

    v = random.choice(plusortimes)                         #start of randomly generated formula
    va = random.choice(plusortimes)
    formula = ""
    while (len(formula) <= (length - 3)):
        formula = formula + random.choice(numbers)
        formula2 = str(v + va + formula)


    kind = ""
    for i in range(2,len(formula2)):
            if i % 2  == 0:
                kind = kind + formula2[i] + formula2[0]
            else:
                kind = kind + formula2[i] + formula2[1]

    formula3 = eval(kind[:-1])

    partial_fmla = "------"

    print "     (JUST TO TRACE, the program invented the formula: )" ,ori
    print "     (JUST TO TRACE, the program evaluated the formula: )",test
    print "The formula you will have to guess has",length,"symbols: ",partial_fmla
    print "You can use digits 1 to 3 and symbols + *"


    guess = raw_input("Please enter an operation symbol or digit: ")



    a = 0
    new = ""
    while a<limit:
        for i in range(len(formula2)):
                if (formula2[i] == partial_fmla[i]):
                    new =  new + partial_fmla[i]


                elif (formula2[i] == guess):
                    new[i] = guess


                else:
                    new[i] =new + "-"


        a = a+1           
        print new

    guess = raw_input("Please enter an operation symbol or digit: ")







    play = raw_input("Do you want to play ? Y - yes, N - no: ")
```

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are trying to do something that you are unable to. If you want to replace characters in a string with a different character, look at [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Answer (score 1):

The following block seems problematic:

```
elif (formula2[i] == guess):
    new[i] = guess
else:
    new[i] =new + "-"
```

Python does not allow modification of characters within strings, as they are immutable (cannot be changed). Try appending the desired character to your `new` string instead. For example:

```
elif formula2[i] == guess:
    new += guess
else:
    new += '-'
```

Finally, you should put the definition of `new` inside the loop directly under, as you want to regenerate it after each guess.

Comment: what do you mean directly under the loop, do you mean the while loop? and i ran it with using new += guess and new += "-" but nothing happened. The program just ended

Comment: Yes, inside of the while loop. Did the program end with an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input("What word would you like to guess: ")
Cor_Let = []
tries = 10
for x in range(len(word)):
        Cor_Let.append("_")
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess == "1":
        break
    for x in range(len(word)):
        word.split()
        guess.split()
        if word[x] == guess:
            Cor_Let[x] = guess
            print(Cor_Let)  
    if guess not in word:
        tries = tries - 1
        print("Wrong you have "+str(tries)+" tries left")

    if list(Cor_Let) == list(word):
        print("Well done")
        print(int(tries)," tries left")
        break
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).